# How can I find out the cell background color in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, colors, background

How can I find out the cell background color in Excel?

Here is what I am trying to do:

1 Select the cell.
[image]

2 Click on the bucket.
[image]

3 Click on the **More Colors...**
[image]

4 Hoping to see the cell background color somewhere here.
[image]

Is it impossible to find out the background color in Excel? Preferable I need a hexadecimal representation of the color.

Update

Using the code provided in comments does not work `Debug.Print Hex(Range("A1").Interior.Color)`: [image]

Comment: Something like `Debug.Print Hex(Range("A1").Interior.Color)`?

Comment: No idea why your dialog box is showing black when you have the yellow cell selected though.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook, where should I put the code in?

Comment: It's VBA code ("Developer tab -> Visual Basic). The method you outline should give you the fill colour of your cell. Are you sure you don't have any conditional formatting?

Comment: MsgBox Selection.Interior.ColorIndex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a custom name get.cell function is a good approach.
Seven background colors are set in cells A1:A7: red, orange, yellow, green, blue, blue and purple.

1. First, select column A, and press Ctrl+F3 to create a new name.
   Name You can enter a name arbitrarily, such as example Name: Background color
2. Reference position input formula: =get.cell(63,Sheet2!$A1)
   (Sheet2!A1 is the A1 cell of the current worksheet, which needs to be filled in according to the actual situation)
3. Click OK to finish creating the new name. Enter the formula in cell B1
   = background color, that is, A1:A7 corresponds to the cell background color number.